# Problem with setState looping inside an array Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Can't find a way to solve my problem its looping correctly the first time but after looping twice in the array I got an error "TypeError: props.imgData[index] is undefined".

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import Image from 'next/image';

export default function SimpleSlider(props) {
   
  let matchingIdArray = props.imgData.findIndex(element => {
    return element.id === props.id 
  })
  
let [index,setIndex] = React.useState(matchingIdArray )
console.log(index)

  let next = () => {    
   setIndex(prev => 
      {
      if(prev <props.imgData.length -1 )       {
       return   prev +1      
        }
        else {
       setIndex(0)
        }
    } )     
  } 
  return (
    <section className="w-full h-screen mx-auto">
  
  <div onClick={next}  className=" w-3/4 mx-auto h-screen  ">      
  <Image src={props.imgData[index].urls.raw} width={props.imgData[index].width} height={props.imgData[index].height} quality={100}  /> 
  </div>
         
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: props.imgData array has undefined because you do not get data from an array using the selected index because the array has no data from that index which you pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `setIndex(0)` instead of `return 0` ? You're not returning anything in this case so you're in fact doing `setState(undefined)`

Comment: Thanks it's fixed ,  I tought setState returned its value by default still have to practice :)

Comment: Glad it fixed your issue! You can mark this answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

according to your code its getting setIndex itself to set function when

```
prev > props.imgData.length -1
```

try to return 0 instead setIndex(0)

```
let next = () => {    
   setIndex(prev => 
      {
      if(prev <props.imgData.length -1 ){
       return   prev +1;
        }
        else {
       return 0;
        }
    } )     
  }
```